# Why doesn't this code break (array of pointers to pointers of record)

Tags: delphi

I'm a bit rusty with pointer code, and don't understand why this code doesn't blow up. Even though I make the node nil, both the pointer arrays seem to still have the reference for the node and can access it without issue, which is not what I expected. 
report memory leaks on shutdown reports no problems.

```
Type

  pNode = ^TNode;
  TNode  =  record
      ID : TNodeIndex;
  end;

  pNodes = ^TNodes;
  TNodes = Array[TNodeArrayRange] of pNode; 





  procedure TForm6.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Source,Dest : pNodes;
    Node : pNode;

  begin             
    //create both arrays
    New(Source);
    fillChar(Source^,Sizeof(Source^),#0);
    New(Dest);
    fillChar(Dest^,Sizeof(Dest^),#0);


   //create a new node
   new(Node);

   //add the node into both source and dest arrays
   Source[0] := Node;
   Dest[0] := Node;


    //output what's in the arrays
    if Source[0] = Dest[0] then 
       ShowMessage('same pointer in both slots');
    if @Source[0]^ = @Dest[0]^ then 
      ShowMessage('same Value in both slots');
    if @Source^[0] <> @Dest^[0] then 
      ShowMessage('Different address in both slots');

   if Source[0] = Node then ShowMessage('Source 0 = node');
   if Dest[0] = Node then ShowMessage('Dest 0 = node');

  //at this point I'm satisfied the next few lines of code should explode
  Dispose(Node);  
  Node := nil;

  Dest[0]^.ID := 4;   //<---- why doesn't this explode? 

  dispose(Source);
  Source := nil;
  dispose(Dest);
  Dest := nil; 
end;
```

Comment: Accessing deallocate memory results in undefined behaviour. No exception being raised is one of the many possible outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tentative answer - I use C++Builder rather than Delphi mainly.

You store a pointer to memory in `Dest[0]` - and nothing removes that pointer.  It's a separate copy of the pointer to the one stored in the other locations.  TNode is a record, not a class and to my understanding (which I admit may be wrong) maps to a structured data record, not a class with a vtable (for despatching functions).

As I understand it when you access a field in a record via a pointer to the record Delphi works out the memory address and accesses that.

So when you aexecute `Dest[0]^.ID := 4` you are writing data into a memory location that you previously allocated.  That memory is still there, and although in theory it may be in use by something else it will be in memory allocated by Delphi and so as you haven't done anything else there's no reason to assume that anything else is currently using that space.

So it doesn't explode because even though you have chosen to write to memory that isn't yours anymore it hasn't affected anything else.

Comment: Such code rarely "explode" immediately, but it will "explode" sometime in the future. Probably during execution of some completely different part of code which makes tracking of such bugs a real nightmare. For instance once I was experiencing a really strange bug where one of my procedures war returning wrong results when used in actual application but correct results during unit testing that I wrote for that procedure. It took me weeks before I realized that I'm corrupting part of application memory by accessing now destroyed object using code much similar to the what OP showed

Comment: Yes - this is a danger, although in the OP all access was in local variables that were out of scope at the end of the function. If you pass a pointer around or save it in a long lived object this is very definitely a danger.  The question was specifically why the assignment did not explode.

Comment: It is true that in OP code example all this is in the scope of a single procedure. But I'm guessing this is because OP provided [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not real code. Real code could be much more complex and have much broader code scope than shown in OP example.

Comment: Is it safe to do this source[0] := nil;  //i.e. make the array slot nil, leave the pointer still non-nil? Assuming not.

Comment: @Derek Seymour - yes it is safe becaus setting Source[0] is setting your local variable which still exists and is allocated.  (Memory is allocated to hold an array of pointers, this is separate from any memory they point to).  It's what the contemnts of Source[0] points to that has gone, not Source[0] itself.

Comment: You have array of pointers so when you set some array item to nil you are actually setting that specific pointer to nil. Wheather this is safe or not largely depends on the rest of your code. For instance if this array item (pointer) was the last pointer/variable/reference to some object and the object hasn't been freed yet it could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @SilverWarrior - in the question he has already freed what Source[0] points to, but in a more generalised case then yes, you should be concerned about memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for feedback really appreciated. Chur bros